# How to enable GZip in a Vapor app?

Tags: swift, gzip, vapor

I found two GitHub repositories, but both of them seem to be outdated:

- https://github.com/vapor-community/gzip-provider
- https://github.com/jhonny-me/GzipMiddleware

The second solution worked fine before Vapor 2.0 release.

I'm using Vapor 2.1 with Swift 3, how can I enable GZip?

Answer (score 1):

As @Quver said, before the Vapor 3 release this isn't going to happen. I do however have some initial work on GZIP for Vapor 3.

For now you'll need to have an nginx proxy set up to do gzip compression for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot... At this moment there is no gzip middleware for Vapor.

Also, probably no-one would be interested in fixing those libs before Vapor 3 release.